# SharePoint: I have an app web hosted list which I created it by this code, but sometimes it disappears

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I don't know why the list can't be found sometimes? while the list in web host won't be disappear.I don't know where is the problem or how to solve it.

```js
function createList() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext();
    var list = context.get_web();
    var listCreation = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
    (listCreation.set_title("MyExpenseList")) 
    listCreation.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.genericList); 
    var olist = list.get_lists().add(listCreation)
    list.update();
    context.load(olist);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onListCreationSuccess, onListCreationFail);
}
function onListCreationSuccess() {
    $('#message').text("List got created");
}
function onListCreationFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to get user name. Error:' + args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The list that I create by the code automatically is deleted without run any code. This is weird. I don't know what is problem.

Comment: where is `SP.ListCreationInformation()` coming from?  are you sure your problem is not in there?  your example seems to be missing enough code to thoroughly debug the problem